# FIND_IN_SET not working on BIT type column

Tags: mysql

**Positive Scenario:**
Column `categories` is of type `String`.

**For Example:**

```
+--------------------------+
|user |categories          |
+--------------------------+
|1    |executive,contractor|
+--------------------------+
|2    |executive           |
+--------------------------+
|3    |client              |
+--------------------------+
```

**Here is the query:**

```
select * from myTable where FIND_IN_SET('executive',`categories`);
```

Above query will return me first two rows as both the users are executive.

**Negative Scenario:**

Column `isExecutable` is of type `BIT`.

**Here is the query:**

```
select * from myTable where FIND_IN_SET(1,`isExecutable`)
```

Above query returns 0 records though there are records having `1` in `isExecutable` column.I do have different columns as well and I am creating dynamic query everytime.So, `FIND_IN_SET` suffices all the requirements except this case.  Is there any way I can make this work using `FIND_IN_SET` only?

Comment: Can you give an example where it *does* work correctly?

Comment: What do you expect to gain by using BIT fields? A bit field still takes up at least one byte of storage

Comment: @Mureinik: I have updated the question.

Comment: @e4c5: BIT fields are used to store boolean values. Either true or False

Comment: But they still take up at least a byte of storage on disk.

Comment: @e4c5: we are only storing 0 & 1

Comment: and that still takes a full byte of storage. Are we going to go on repeating this inifinitely?

Answer (score 1):

As MySQL documentation on [find_in_set()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) says, it works with strings, not with `bit` data type. That's the reason it is failing.

So, you need to convert your `isExecutable` field into list of 1s and 0s separated by comma into a single string, and this is what [export_set()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_export-set) function is designed to do:

```
select * from myTable where FIND_IN_SET('1',export_set(`isExecutable`,'1','0',',')
```

However, you do not need this string conversion, since if any of the bits are set to 1, then its value is more than 0.

```
select * from myTable where isExecutable > 0b0
```

or

```
select * from myTable where isExecutable + 0 > 0
```

UPDATE

In subsequent comments to the question the OP stated that the field is used for marking true or false (0 or 1). Therefore, using export_set - find_in_set makes even less sense. Just check for numeric 0 or 1:

```
 select * from myTable where isExecutable + 0 = 1
```